# How to get week beginning date in DB2?

Tags: date, db2, week-number

Using DB2, without a calendar lookup, How do I determine the Sunday of the week to which a certain date belongs? For example, give a set of dates:

```
date
----------
2015-05-01
2015-05-02
2015-05-03
2015-05-04
2015-05-05
2015-05-06
2015-05-07
```

how do I find the date corresponding to the beginning of the week for each date, i.e. if it's Sunday it's `'2015-04-26'`

```
date        wc
----------  ----------
2015-05-01  2015-04-26
2015-05-02  2015-04-26
2015-05-03  2015-05-03
2015-05-04  2015-05-03
2015-05-05  2015-05-03
2015-05-06  2015-05-03
2015-05-07  2015-05-03
```

I've found many solutions to find "week number" but I need this as a date data type.

Comment: "Using DB2" of what version and platform? Some have the `DAYOFWEEK` function...

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like `((current date) - (dayofweek(current date)-1) days)` does the trick. The expression returns the Sunday of the current week.

DAYOFWEEK is a function to return the day for a given date or timestamp with Sunday being "1".